# objective-c get NSURLRequest request execution time

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

Is there any way to get the actual request execution time from NSURLRequest / NSURLResponse / NSURLConnection?

Thanx!

Comment: What do you mean? The time taken to open connection, send the request, receive the header, receive data?

Comment: oh i'm sorry yes the time consumed to receive the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the time it takes to receive all data just implement two NSURLConnectionDelegate methods: in `connection:didReceiveResponse` save the first timestamp; then in `connectionDidFinishLoading` just subtract the current by it.

Btw, you should implement connection:didFailWithError too.

Comment: yes i already have those to manage the request, i thought about there must be a method to get the execution time without messing with timestamps on my own.

Comment: Not with NSURLConnection, I heard ASIHTTPRequest is like NSURLConnection on steroids, maybe you should have a look at it, but it's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't tried ASIHttpRequest but for every one who has to implement the time count on your own you should have a look at this http://vladimir.zardina.org/2011/01/measuring-execution-time-of-your-objective-c-code-at-runtime/ for a generic approach.